isc-dhcp on commit script not executed in /usr/local/bin
My god... I've spend my entire evening on something I still don't understand at all..
I am integrating samba active directory on my ubuntu server (that does work great btw!). But I also want dhcp to update samba's internal dns server, so that whenever I add a computer it will be found by the dns server.
So, I found this page on samba. At some point, the page explains I should modify my dhcpd.conf, add a few sections, on for "on commit" and have these sections call the script they share on the page I linked.
All good, all simple. I thought.
Copied the script into the path /usr/local/bin as the page described. Restart dhcpd, and wait for one of my computers to send a dhcp request. And there it began
2024-09-18T20:45:50.859538+02:00 server dhcpd[8989]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.2.220 from 44:07:0b:a9:ae:44 (Google-Home-Mini) via enp5s0
2024-09-18T20:45:50.862103+02:00 server dhcpd[8989]: DHCPACK on 192.168.2.220 to 44:07:0b:a9:ae:44 (Google-Home-Mini) via enp5s0
2024-09-18T20:45:54.596932+02:00 server dhcpd[8989]: Commit: IP: 192.168.2.220 DHCID: 44:07:0b:a9:ae:44 Name: Google-Home-Mini
2024-09-18T20:45:54.597007+02:00 server dhcpd[8989]: execute_statement argv[0] = /usr/local/bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh
2024-09-18T20:45:54.597154+02:00 server dhcpd[10508]: Unable to execute /usr/local/bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh: Permission denied
2024-09-18T20:45:54.597201+02:00 server kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1726685154.596:669): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="exec" class="file" info="profile transition not found" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/dhcpd" name="/usr/local/bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh" pid=10508 comm="dhcpd" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=105 ouid=105 target="/usr/local/bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh"


Well, it began with app armor declining, so got that out of the way. For testing purposes even stopped app armor all together, but no joy. Permission denied.
Googled and googled, tried all I could find. Nothing. Chat gpt, multiple times. I got nothing.
Ended up with sudo chmod 777 every step of the path towards the script file (the script file included ofc). Nothing.
Then finally I thought (last resort) lets move the script file to another folder. I copied the script file from /usr/local/bin to /usr/sbin`. That's all. AND IT WORKS???
Why... how... ? What the hell is going on here? Why is user dhcpd allowed to execute a script in /usr/sbin but is somehow (NOT by filesystem permissions!) not allowed to execute it from /usr/local/bin? To me that makes no sense at all, I hope somebody is willing to shed a light on this

Best starting point in understanding your issue is the Ubuntu product & release you're using; as defaults change over time, and the release details allow us to know what your system expects.  What are you running?

"Ended up with sudo chmod 777 every step" more is not always better - some programs will actually refuse to use files if they are too permissive. Is your /usr/local on a separate filesystem? If so, what are its mount options (ex. findmnt -T /usr/local/bin)?

Hmm, no no separate file systems. Just one mount point /. And I think I recognize what you mean, e.g. ssh doesn't like can refuse pem files if they are too open. But would that also apply for executing a program? Anyway, with either all steps in the path to chmod 755 or chmod 777 made no difference.
